# NHibernate Search - _hibernate_class problem

Tags: .net, nhibernate.search

I have this mapped class called as "Client" used for NHibernate and is decorated with Lucene search attributes. When NHibernate.Search does initial indexing, I found through Luke that the special property _hibernate_class shows following value for some documents(index docs)...

CProxyTypeABC_Common_EntitiesClientEntities_NHibernate_ProxyINHibernateProxy1, DynamicAssemblyProxyGen, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

But for some documents following value is shown...

ABC.Common.Entities.User, FAOCommon, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Strange thing is, the document(index doc) OR records with first value are not searchable through full index query where as full text query returns correct value for records indexed in the document with property shown second.

Not sure while indexing, why would some document contain _hibernate_class value as shown in the first example ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in NH Search, you shouldn't be able to get this in the index
Please post a repro to the NH mailing list